# Ignore lines with same next fields as previous

Tags: linux, perl, unix, command

I have a file contents of which looks like this

```
123,1,ABC,DEF
123,1,ABC
345,4,TZY
456,3,XYZ
333,4,TTT,YYY
333,4,TTT
```

I want to ignore lines with the previous and next contents the same i.e lines containing 123 and 333

Output needs to be

```
345,4,TZY
456,3,XYZ
```

Any ideas on how to go about this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TMTOWTDI:

```
my $str = join '', <>;
$str =~ s/^(\d+).+\n(\1.+\n)+//mg;
print $str;
```

EDIT: first line can also be replaced with Randal L. Schwartz's slurp:

```
my $str = do { local $/; <HANDLE> }; #
```

Comment: This is **really** cool, but performance will degrade dramatically on very large file since you're slurping. I posted a solution that is constant memory use (albeit, much wordier and less cool) below

Comment: Also, as per perl best practices, you should use File::Slurp to slurp the file in the first place.

Comment: @DVK Yeah, definitely no good for big files. I was trying to come up with a slick map-grep-map solution to the problem, but it got ugly fast. Still mulling it over...

Answer (score 1):

TMTOWDI

```
my $last_prefix = ""; 
my $last_line = ""; 
while (<>) { check_line($_); }
check_line("");    sub check_line {
    my $line = shift;
    my ($prefix) = ($line =~ /^([^,]*),/); 
    if (($prefix || "") ne $last_prefix ) {
        print $last_line;
        $last_line = $_;
    } else {
        $last_line = "";
    };
    $last_prefix = $prefix; 

}
```

This is wordy but I suspect the performance might be better than regexp on a very large file.

Answer (score 0):

try the uniq utility

uniq -w 3 your_file.txt

would do the trick. no need for perl

Comment: You need to add the -u flag to produce the desired output (see the question)

Comment: also, -w argument to uniq may not be supported on every Unix (it is not on Solaris 10)